# Почему в "намереваться" гласный е?

Tags: правописание, морфология

Как объяснить, что в слове *намер**е**ваться* пишется гласный **е**, а не **и**? Каким правилом это определить?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Объясняется "книжным" происхождением глагола, т.е. старославянским или псевдо-старославянским (точно не знаю). Отсюда "болгарский" итеративный суффикс *-ова-/-ева-* вместо исконно русского *-ыва-/-ива-*. То же самое в *повелевать*, например.

Парный глагол *вознамериться* расширяется уже "по-нашему": *вознамериваться*.

Comment: А не потому, что *намер**е**ваться* происходит от *намер**е**ние*?

Comment: С чего бы глаголу происходить от отглагольного существительного?

Comment: Да, и правда. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Это зависит от ударения.

*намéриваться*, форма глагола *намерить* пишется через и, но имеет другой смысл.

Answer (score 0):

В правилах о правописании суффиксов глаголов ова/ева - ыва/ива есть ряд слов для запоминания: застревать, продлевать и др. Намереваться - из этого ряда